# CosmosDb not using the ContractResolver provided when generating select queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a project where I'm using CosmosDb (SQL API) as my database. It's a .Net Core project and I'm using the latest stable NuGet packages.

The document client is created as follows and use a custom contract resolver.

```
new DocumentClient(new Uri(settings.DatabaseUri), settings.DatabaseKey,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new PrivateSetterCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
        {
           new EmailJsonConverter()
        }
     });
```

I have a collection called `EmailAccount`

```
public class EmailAccount : Entity
{
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public EmailAccount(DDD.Core.ValueObjects.Email email,
        string displayName)
    {
        Email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
        DisplayName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName) ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(displayName)) : displayName;
    }
}
```

All the properties are converted into camel-case when serialized which all works fine. But the problem is when I try to filter the documents. The SQL query that's generated looks something like this when I try to filter by the Email.

```
SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root["Email"] = "amila@iagto.com")
```

The problem is with the case of the property (`Email`). The property in the database is `email` but the query generator doesn't seem to be adhering to the `ContractResolver` provided and generates the above sql query which doesn't return any result.

If I put `[JsonProperty("email")]` above the Email property, the query is generated properly. Anyway to get the query generated properly without using attributes in the `Entity` class?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JsonSerializerSettings` at the `CreateDocumentQuery` level for the LINQ to SQL to pick it up.

This property was added in the SDK on 2.0.0+ versions.

Comment: I've tried that providing `JsonSerializerSettings` in the `FeedOptions` of `CreateDocumentQuery`, and it still produce the same query `SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root["Email"] = "amila@iagto.com")`

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. You can report it in the cosmosdb .net sdk github repo.

Comment: Thanks Nick, will do. I'll first try a separate console application to see if it's not a bug somewhere in my own code.

Comment: Also it worths setting the JsonSettings at the global level and see what that does.

Comment: setting the ContractResolver at DocumentClient level does the job. Tested with SDK 2.3.0